# In Sales Order Grid Some Fields Data are Repeated

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I Have Create Module That Add Some Field In Sales Order Gid,
but That Field Data Are Repeated, When More Order Are Placed.

[image]

[image]

**Product Type,
Quantity Ordered,
Product Id,
Product Name,
Sku**

are repeated in order grid

**Observer.php Code**

```
    <?php

class Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Model_Observer
{

    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        //$select = $collection->getSelect();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft
                (array
                    ('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 
                     'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method')
                );  

         $collection->join
                (array
                    ('soa' => 'sales/order_address'), 
                    'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', 
                        array('full_address'=>'CONCAT(soa.firstname, " " , soa.lastname, ",<br/>", soa.street, ",<br/>", soa.city, ",<br/>", soa.region, ",<br/>", soa.postcode)' ), 
                        null,'left'
                );

         $collection->join
                (array
                    ('soas' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type = "shipping"', 
                        array('full_address_ship'=>'CONCAT(soas.firstname, " " , soas.lastname, ",<br/>", soas.street, ",<br/>", soas.city, ",<br/>", soas.region, ",<br/>", soas.postcode)' ), 
                        null,'left'
                );

        $customer_entity = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');        
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
               $customer_entity,
               'main_table.customer_id = '.$customer_entity.'.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'email')
               );   

        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                    'sales_flat_order_item', 
                    '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', 
                        array(
                              'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                              'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'productids' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'quantityordereds' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'types' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_type SEPARATOR ",")')
                             )
                 );

        $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    }

}
```

**Data.php Code**

```
 <?php

class Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{


    /* public function getIsEnable()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('sigmasolve_customordergrid/general/enabled');
    } */

    public function getSkusColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'SKU',
            'index' => 'skus',
            'type' => 'text',
        );
    }

    public function getNamesColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Product Name',
            'index' => 'names',
            'type' => 'text',
        );
    }

    public function getProductidsColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Product Id',
            'index' => 'productids',
            'type' => 'text',
        );
    }

    public function getQuantityorderedsColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Quantity Ordered',
            'index' => 'quantityordereds',
            'type' => 'text',
        );
    }

    public function getProducttypesColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Type',
            'index' => 'types',
            'type' => 'text',
        );
    }

    public function getImagesColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header'    => 'Image',
            'align'     => 'left',
            'index'     => 'images',
            'width'     => '70',
            //'filter_condition_callback' => array('Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Model_Observer', 'filterImages'),
        );
    } 


}
```

**Collection.php Code**

```
    <?php

class Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Model_Resource_Sales_Order_Grid_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection
{
    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();

        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order') {
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)");

            $havingCondition = $countSelect->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
            if (count($havingCondition)) {
                $countSelect->where(
                    str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ')", 'sales_flat_order_item.sku', $havingCondition[0])
                );
                $countSelect->where(
                    str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ', ')",'sales_flat_order_item.name', $havingCondition[0])
                );
                $countSelect->where(
                    str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR ', ')",'sales_flat_order_item.product_id', $havingCondition[0])
                );
                $countSelect->where(
                    str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ', ')",'sales_flat_order_item.qty_ordered', $havingCondition[0])
                );
                $countSelect->where(
                    str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_type SEPARATOR ', ')",'sales_flat_order_item.product_type', $havingCondition[0])
                );
                $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
            }
        }

        return $countSelect;
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id')
            ->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at')
            ->addFilterToMap('updated_at', 'main_table.updated_at');
        return parent::_initSelect();
    }
}
```

**customordergrid.xml layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Payment Type</header>
                    <index>payment_method</index>
                    <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
             <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>customer_email</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Email</header>
                    <index>customer_email</index>
                    <filter_index>customer.email</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>full_address</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Billing Address</header>
                    <index>full_address</index>
                    <filter_index>soa.billing</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>full_address_ship</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Shipping Address</header>
                    <index>full_address_ship</index>
                    <filter_index>soas.shipping</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>full_address</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>skus</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getSkusColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>images</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getImagesColumnParams" />
                <after>created_at</after>
            </action>
             <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>names</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getNamesColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>producdtids</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getProductidsColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>quantityordereds</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getQuantityorderedsColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>types</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getProducttypesColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hello,
I Have Solved My Question,in Observer FIle, Merge COde. in one collection

Comment: I have posted my code in updated observer file

Comment: my whole code i have posted.