# How to add product image in sales order grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

How to add product image in sales order grid.
Using Observer.

I have to create custom module,
in this module i have to add product image that selected in place order.

i have to use observer for getting data. from the tables.

**observer.php file**

```
<?php

class Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Model_Observer
{

    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        //$select = $collection->getSelect();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft
                (array
                    ('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 
                     'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', 
                      array('payment_method' => 'method')
                );  

         $collection->join
                (array
                    ('soa' => 'sales/order_address'), 
                     'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', 
                        array('full_address'=>'CONCAT(soa.firstname, " " , soa.lastname, ",<br/>", soa.street, ",<br/>", soa.city, ",<br/>", soa.region, ",<br/>", soa.postcode)' ), 
                        null,'left'
                );

         $collection->join
                (array
                    ('soas' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type = "shipping"', 
                        array('full_address_ship'=>'CONCAT(soas.firstname, " " , soas.lastname, ",<br/>", soas.street, ",<br/>", soas.city, ",<br/>", soas.region, ",<br/>", soas.postcode)' ), 
                        null,'left'
                );

        $customer_entity = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');        
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
               $customer_entity,
               'main_table.customer_id = '.$customer_entity.'.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'email')
               );   

        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                    'sales_flat_order_item', 
                    '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', 
                        array(
                              'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                              'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'productids' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'quantityordereds' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ",")'),
                              'types' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.product_type SEPARATOR ",")')
                             )
                 );

        $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add image display query?

Comment: I think you need to use renderer to get images on orders grid, add a new column to your grid and render product images to that column

Comment: If Suppose you have order three products onces then in sale's order which image You what to show in sales order grid

Comment: all three images can display as SEPARATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code for images in your layout file.

```
<action method="addColumnAfter"> 
    <columnId>images</columnId> 
    <arguments> 
        <header>Image</header> 
        <index>productids</index> 
        <filter></filter>
        <renderer>Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Images</renderer> 
        <width>70</width> 
    </arguments> 
    <after>created_at</after> 
</action>
```

Now create a new file **app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Customordergrid\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Images.php** with below code

```
<?php 
class Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Images extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return $this->_geProductImages($row);
    } 
    protected function _geProductImages(Varien_Object $row)
    {   
        $result = '';
        $products = explode(",",$row->getData('productids'));
            foreach($products as $productId) {
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                if(($_product->getImage() != '') && ($_product->getImage() != "no_selection")) {
                    $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
                    $result .= "<img src=". $imageUrl ." width='50' height='50'/>"; 
                } 

            }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

It will show you images like below. You can add css to update structure as per your requirements.

[image]

Comment: I want to get image using observer

Comment: public function getImagesColumnParams()
 {
  return array(
            'header'  => 'Image',
            'align'  => 'left',
            'index'     => 'images',
            'width'     => '70',
            //'filter_condition_callback' => array('Sigmasolve_Customordergrid_Model_Observer', 'filterImages'),
        );
 }

Comment: that type of code create for the image field

Comment: and in design->adminhtml  creating layout file, that layout file has a code like....



<action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>images</columnId>
                <arguments helper="sigmasolve_customordergrid/getImagesColumnParams" />
                <after>payment_method</after>
            </action>

Comment: Can you please add these details to your question? It will be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: ok i will upload my all code

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166312/in-sales-order-grid-some-fields-data-are-repeated

Comment: my all code has this question only difference is observer.php, this differnce has in my above current code

Comment: I have upload completed code in above link. @Jaimin Sutariya

Comment: Please check my edits. @RushikeshSolanki

Comment: when i rewrite grid give me error

Comment: when i rewrite grid give me error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in C:\xampp2\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291

Comment: i think renderer is not worked

Comment: Yo don't need to rewrite grid now. Only use edit code. update your `getImagesColumnParams` function and create single file app\code\community\Sigmasolve\Customordergrid\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Renderer\ProductImages.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56163/discussion-between-rushikesh-solanki-and-jaimin-sutariya).